# Matrix3D.pointAt in Silverlight 3.0

Tags: silverlight-3.0, matrix

Has anyone one every created a method for Silverlight which does the same thing as Matrix3D.pointAt() does in Flash?  In flash pointAt rotates a display object so that it faces a specified position.  In my situation I want it to face the same direction as its velocity vector.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at Silverlight 3 plane projection which may achieve what you're trying to do: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/ContinuumNews/Silverlight-PlaneProjection-perspective-transform-tutorial/